# Auto check for user roles on login handler instead checking with sessions on every page?

Tags: php

I am trying to add a login to my site. I searched on the internet for examples I found two login systems

[This one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205693/php-login-checker-stage) and [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234821/php-secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies-with-referer-url)

I want to use the second one [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234821/php-secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies-with-referer-url) looks more complete to me. I am not a coder and I need your advice.

I do check for user role with this code on every protected page

```
if(!$isLoggedIn || $_SESSION["role"] != admin) {
    echo "you dont have permissions to access this page";
    exit();
}elseif(!$isLoggedIn || $_SESSION["role"] != normal){
    echo "you dont have permissions to access this page";
    exit();
}elseif(!$isLoggedIn || $_SESSION["role"] != notactive){
    echo "you must update your account";
    exit();
}
```

First question. How can I integrate above codes with cookie check in sessionCheck.php

```
require_once "Auth.php";
require_once "Util.php";

$auth = new Auth();
$util = new Util();

// Get Current date, time
$current_time = time();
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_time);

// Set Cookie expiration for 1 month
$cookie_expiration_time = $current_time + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // for 1 month

$isLoggedIn = false;

// Check if loggedin session and redirect if session exists
if(!empty($_SESSION["uid"])) {
    $isLoggedIn = true;
}
// Check if loggedin session exists
else if(!empty($_COOKIE["member_login"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_password"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_selector"])) {
    // Initiate auth token verification directive to false
    $isPasswordVerified = false;
    $isSelectorVerified = false;
    $isExpiryDateVerified = false;

    // Get token for username
    $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($_COOKIE["member_login"],0);

    // Validate random password cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_password"], $userToken[0]["password_hash"])) {
        $isPasswordVerified = true;
    }

    // Validate random selector cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_selector"], $userToken[0]["selector_hash"])) {
        $isSelectorVerified = true;
    }

    // check cookie expiration by date
    if($userToken[0]["expiry_date"] >= $current_date) {
        $isExpiryDareVerified = true;
    }

    // Redirect if all cookie based validation retuens true
    // Else, mark the token as expired and clear cookies
    if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"]) && $isPasswordVerified && $isSelectorVerified && $isExpiryDareVerified) {
        $isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
        if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
            $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
        }
        // clear cookies
        $util->clearAuthCookie();
    }
}
```

The second question which one you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work assuming `$userToken` contains the `role` attribute.

```
require_once "Auth.php";
require_once "Util.php";

$auth = new Auth();
$util = new Util();

// Get Current date, time
$current_time = time();
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_time);

// Set Cookie expiration for 1 month
$cookie_expiration_time = $current_time + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // for 1 month

$isLoggedIn = false;
$role = null;

// Check if loggedin session and redirect if session exists
if(!empty($_SESSION["uid"])) {
    $isLoggedIn = true;
    $role = (isset($_SESSION["role"]) ? $_SESSION["role"] : null);
}
// Check if loggedin session exists
else if(!empty($_COOKIE["member_login"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_password"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_selector"])) {
    // Initiate auth token verification directive to false
    $isPasswordVerified = false;
    $isSelectorVerified = false;
    $isExpiryDateVerified = false;

    // Get token for username
    $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($_COOKIE["member_login"],0);

    // Validate random password cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_password"], $userToken[0]["password_hash"])) {
        $isPasswordVerified = true;
    }

    // Validate random selector cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_selector"], $userToken[0]["selector_hash"])) {
        $isSelectorVerified = true;
    }

    // check cookie expiration by date
    if($userToken[0]["expiry_date"] >= $current_date) {
        $isExpiryDareVerified = true;
    }

    // Redirect if all cookie based validation retuens true
    // Else, mark the token as expired and clear cookies
    if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"]) && $isPasswordVerified && $isSelectorVerified && $isExpiryDareVerified) {
        $isLoggedIn = true;
        $role = (isset($userToken[0]["role"]) ? $userToken[0]["role"] : null);
    } else {
        if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
            $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
        }
        // clear cookies
        $util->clearAuthCookie();
    }
}

if (!$isLoggedIn || $role != "admin") {
    echo "you dont have permissions to access this page";
    exit();
} else if (!$isLoggedIn || $role != "normal") {
    echo "you dont have permissions to access this page";
    exit();
} else if (!$isLoggedIn || $role != "notactive") {
    echo "you must update your account";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: my question wasnt clear enough I am sorry. I wanted to integrate it with cookies. I am realy sorry

Comment: My fault, I thought u ment integrate it with `sessionCheck.php` file. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to apologize, your question was clear, you wrote `How can I integrate above codes with cookie check in sessionCheck.php` I just read a little bit too fast.